# Why does the following code generate 4 elements instead of 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to understand, why does the following code generate FOUR new paragraphs instead of just TWO.

Could anyone explain what exactly happens in the `$("p").before($("p").clone());` part?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").before($("p").clone());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>paragraph 1.</p>
<p>paragraph 2.</p>

<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you create a code snippet for this? It'd make it easier for us to see what behaviour is actually causing problems.

Comment: Make a screenshot of the result and post it here.

Comment: Need to realize that internally `$(selector).someMethod()` does an internal loop over all elements in the collection created by `$(selector)`

Answer (score 2):

Clone copies each of `<p>` and returns two paragraph elements which are inserted by before.

**A more meaningful explanation:**

- You have got two `<p>` elements in your HTML.
- `$("p").clone()` clones BOTH elements and passes them to `before()`
- `before()` is executed TWICE, one time for each paragraph

As output, you get 2*2 = 4 new paragraphs.

Comment: I believe the question is why does it generate 4 instead of 2.

Comment: Reasoning is flawed. `before()` does not create anything itself

Comment: @char ahh I have ill phrased it, a second

Comment: @char fixed that. That's what you get when you sleep two hours at night :)

Comment: Thank you. That answered my question very well.

Comment: @user You're welcome! Don't forget you can click the checkmark that would mean that my answer solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

$("p").clone() alone results

[image]

then $("p").before($("p").clone()) means it will append the result of $("p").clone() before both paragraph tags.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you `clone()`, it creates a deep copy of the `p` elements.

`before()` will append the copies not only to the existing elements, but also to the cloned elements.

Use a more specific class name to append them, not $("p"), especially when the cloned elements and elements you are inserting before is the same type of element.

At least use different element like this.

`$("p").clone().appendTo('body');`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").clone().appendTo('.clone-target');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>paragraph 1.</p>
<p>paragraph 2.</p>
<div class="clone-target"></div>
<button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>

</body>
</html>
```